# How to detect REST API request?

Tags: 7, users, services

I have one defined endpoint in Services.

I need to detect if request origin is browser or REST client app in [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) implementation to prevent custom redirect when using service.

My solution is simple [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) + [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7).

But maybe there is a better way. Not found any for now.

Comment: I think URI is as good as anything, unless your client can send a header you can look for. Services/rest_server don't seem to leave any clues that they're involved in the current request in a resource callback